# any free/opensource image editor or java program to make white color transparent in a gif icon image?

Tags: java, image-editing

I am using software to edit an icon, the orignal transparent background becomes white after editing and can not make it back.

IS there any free easy editor to change whilte color to transparent or is there any easy java program to do so.   Both are ok for me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) is a strong candidate as an image editor.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970208/png-transparency-without-alpha-channel) discusses transparency in Java with .png files

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out [paint.net](http://www.paint.net/)

Comment: I like paint.net. Open source, excellent UI. Plugins available to handle more image options. I always find gimp's UI too clunky.

Answer (score 0):

The gimp is something you may want to look at:  [gimp](http://www.gimp.org)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try the online paint tools at [aviary.com](http://www.aviary.com)